# Python format default rounding when formatting float number

Tags: python, floating-point, numbers, format

I'm trying to solve some floating-point problems in my code in Python 2.7.10. When testing I've encountered a strange behaviour with the `format` method:

```
print "{}".format(0.3000000000004) # 13 decimals
```

Prints: `0.3`

But:

```
print "{}".format(0.300000000004) # 12 decimals
```

Prints: `0.300000000004`

Since I'm not specifying the format, why does it round the first number? Is there a default number of allowed decimal places?

Comment: You are just seeing that the default `str()` conversion formats to 12 decimals, while `repr()` shows more.

Comment: The behavior is different in Python 3 (3.6 at least)

Comment: @Chris_Rands: yes, precision was changed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks; can you elaborate at all?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I was planning to look for a suitable dupe (but out of battery and time for the moment).

Comment: @Chris_Rands: [Why does str(float) return more digits in Python 3 than Python 2?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25898733) for the Py 2 vs 3 changes.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: in-depth explanation for how things are formatted when using `str()` vs `repr()`: [Precision of repr(f), str(f), print(f) when f is float](//stackoverflow.com/q/28493114)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you do not specify a format, the default type coercion to string is used. So this isn't really an issue with `format`. Python 2 truncates to a precision of 12 characters (excluding the leading zero, if any) for `float.__str__`, and after truncation in this case, all trailing zeros are cleaned up:

```
>>> str(0.3000000000004) # unlike str(0.3000000000014) -> '0.300000000001'
'0.3'
```

Adding the `format_spec` `:f` gives you the default precision of 6:

```
>>> '{:f}'.format(0.3000000000004)
'0.300000'
```

Specify the width and precision or use `repr` to get a good representation:

```
>>> '{!r}'.format(0.3000000000004)
'0.3000000000004'
```

The behavior is different in Python 3 though:

```
>>> str(0.3000000000004)
'0.3000000000004'
```

---

The formatting of floats is handled by just one function [`float_repr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/floatobject.c#L312) in Python 3 (it does not have a special `float_str` function):

```
(reprfunc)float_repr,                       /* tp_repr */
...
(reprfunc)float_repr,                        /* tp_str */
```

whereas Python2.7 defines a separate handler [`float_str`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/floatobject.c#L396) and [`float_repr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/floatobject.c#L390) for `__str__` and `__repr__` respectively:

```
(reprfunc)float_repr,                       /* tp_repr */
...
(reprfunc)float_str,                        /* tp_str */
```

The deciding variable here which I think is the reason for the precision loss beyond 12d.p. is `PyFloat_STR_PRECISION` (defined in Python 2):

```
#define PyFloat_STR_PRECISION 12
```

It reverses to a truncation for floats taking more than 12 characters in the default conversion.

Comment: But `str(0.3000000000004)` `return`s `'0.3000000000004'` in Py3.6

Comment: @Chris_Rands A lot has changed with strings, between 2.7 and 3.6, so I wouldn't consider that as surprising

Comment: Didn't say it was surprising, but it's not intuitive (to me at least) so perhaps it is worth explaining in your answer :)

Comment: Ok it make sense, i just wanted to know if it was an expected behaviour. Then can i be sure that this rounding solves floating-point problems on number to string conversion?

Comment: @Chris_Rands took some time to walk through the c code, but there you have it

Answer (score -3):

This is just the way python (and many other languages) deal with float point inaccuracy. So internally this number is actually equals 0.3. There's a website dedicated to this problem in many languages: http://0.30000000000000004.com/

To this specific print, you can simply quote the number (make it a string), and the compiler will not try to round the number:

```
print "{}".format("0.3000000000004")
```

But then you also wouldn't need to use the format:

```
print "0.3000000000004"
```

Comment: No, this is about formatting accuracy, not general FP accuracy.

Comment: It is not possible for an IEEE 754 binary floating point number to have the value 0.3. The closest 64 bit binary float is 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875